# How to Install and Use PKCS12 certificate in android?

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, pkcs#12

I'm trying to install a .p12 certificate from device storage and read it for ssl connection but unfortunately i cant read or find the installed certificate in user trusted credentials.
what can i do to install this kind of certificate and read it?
i don't want to read it from storage so that i have to use password and file path code like below:

```
        InputStream inputStream = AppController.getInstance().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert);
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(inputStream, clientCertPassword.toCharArray());
```

Comment: Hi is this for SSL-pinning?

Comment: I think this might help you. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#CertificatePinning

Comment: i don't want to add the certificate to raw folder either, just install it on device and use it

Comment: If you don't want to use your certificate in your code, You can use https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit-Android#configuring-a-pinning-policy

Comment: I need to use the installed certificate

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are asking about SSL-pinning, I have no idea about his process, I just read about this here..

https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/installing-certificates-onto-android-devices/